# Get all columns in cassandra query

Tags: java, astyanax, cassandra-2.0

My cql3 table is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_details (
  customer_id int,
  uuid text,
  creation_time timestamp,
  agent text,
  address text,
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, uuid)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='NONE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

public class CustomerCF {

    private static String columnFamilyName = "customer";
    @Component(ordinal = 0)
    private String uuid;
    @Component(ordinal = 1)
    private String columnName;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }
    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }
    public static String getColumnFamilyName() {
        return columnFamilyName;
    }

}
```

i query in cql3 :

```
select * from customer_details where customer_id=1 and uuid='0xxiyj';

customer_id | uuid    | creation_time              | agent              | address
-------------+---------------+--------------------------+----------------------+----------
          11 | 0xxiyj | 1970-01-01 05:30:00+0530 | My agent |    india
```

I have been trying to do its ORM equivalent in astyanax.

Max i could get close to is

```
AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<CustomerCF> recordEntitySerializer = new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<CustomerCF>(CustomerCF.class);
             ColumnFamily<Integer,CustomerCF> recordColumnFamily = this.buildColumnFamily(CustomerCF.getColumnFamilyName(), customerId, recordEntitySerializer);
                try {
                        //OperationResult<ColumnList<CustomerCF>> result = astyanaxKeyspace.prepareQuery(recordColumnFamily).getKey(customerId).withColumnRange(recordEntitySerializer.buildRange()
                               // .withPrefix('0xxiyj')).execute();
                        CustomerCF recordCF = new CustomerCF();
                        recordCF.setUuid('0xxiyj');
                        recordCF.setColumnName("address");
                        CustomerCF recordCF1 = new CustomerCF();
                        recordCF.setUuid('0xxiyj');
                        recordCF1.setColumnName("agent");
                        List<CustomerCF> list = new ArrayList<CustomerCF>();
                        list.add(recordCF);list.add(recordCF1);
                        OperationResult<ColumnList<CustomerCF>> result = astyanaxKeyspace.prepareQuery(recordColumnFamily).getKey(customerId).withColumnSlice(list).execute();
                        for (Column<CustomerCF> row : result.getResult()) {
                            System.out.println(row.getName().getColumnName()+" "+row.getStringValue());
                        }
                } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
```

which is equivalent to

```
select address, agent from customer_details where customer_id=1 and uuid='0xxiyj';
```

How do i write ORM equivalent of

```
select * from customer_details where customer_id=1 and uuid='0xxiyj';
```

Also 1 more & most imp. question : if in the above case there the primary key is `(customer_id,uuid,agent,address)`, how can i query equivalent of

```
select agent,address from customer_details where customer_id=1 and uuid='0xxiyj';
```

in ORM

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kundera for it. 
Its very simple to use.

you can find it at following link
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera

also you can refer
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes

Comment: Thanks...but i have programmed 90% of my project in astyanax, so will have to stick to it.